# i386 ubuntu touch emulator

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, emulation

I follow the [touch emulator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator) to create an emulator, and when I try create one with i386 arch with the code:

```
sudo ubuntu-emulator create --arch=i386 myinstance
```

I get the follow error:

```
unknown flag `arch'
```

more information:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-emulator create -h

Usage:
  ubuntu-emulator [OPTIONS] create [create-OPTIONS]

Creates a new emulator instance name 'name' by downloading the necessary components from the image server

Help Options:
  -h, --help          Show this help message

Create new emulator instance named 'name':
      --channel=      Select device channel (ubuntu-touch/devel)
      --server=       Select image server (https://system-image.ubuntu.com)
      --revision=     Select revision
      --use-raw-disk  Use raw disks instead of qcow2

Help Options:
  -h, --help          Show this help message

$ sudo ubuntu-emulator -h
Usage:
  ubuntu-emulator [OPTIONS]

Help Options:
  -h, --help  Show this help message

Available commands:
  create    Create new emulator instance named 'name'
  destroy   Destroys an emulator instance named 'name'
  list      Lists emulator instances
  run       Run emulator instance named 'name'
  snapshot  Manipulates snapshots for emulator instance named 'name'

$ uname -a
Linux Inspiron 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

any idea why the arch option is not show and on instructions page exists this option?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue. I think it's related to using the version of ubuntu-emulator that comes with the Ubuntu SDK instead of grabbing it from the phablet-team/tools PPA.

That is my best guess based off of this howto. http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/ubuntu-touch-emulator-installation-and.html